# how do I execute the drawing of the roof in processing

Tags: processing

im confused as to how to get the parameters incorporated properly when trying to construct a roof in processing, for a car I am trying to draw with a square roof using the rect function.

```
    void setup()
{
  size(700,400);
  drawRoof(10,40,30,30);
}

void drawRoof(int x,int y, int width, int height)
{
  rect(x,y,width,height);
}

void rect(int x,int y, int width, int height)
{
  
}                                                    // Draw square roof
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the rect function; it's already built into Processing.  You will need a draw() function; just call your drawRoof() function from there as needed. However, you should see a rectangle just from your setup code if you add draw().  'Width' and 'height' are keywords in Processing which have to do with display width and height, therefore I would also recommend that you choose other words specific to your project, eg, roofW and roofH.